# Best way to avoid cast integer to pointer when dealing with memory access (MISRA 2008)

Tags: c, casting, embedded, bare-metal, misra

I have a bare-metal program(driver) which reads/writes some memory-mapped registers.
e.g:

```
void foo_read(uint64_t reg_base, uint32_t *out_value)
{
    *out = READREG(reg_base + FOO_REG_OFFSET);
}
```

- reg_base is the base address of the memory-mapped device (64-bit
  address)
- FOO_REG_OFFSET is the offset of the register (`#define FOO_REG_OFFSET 
  0x00000123`). Register "foo" is 32-bit "wide".

READREG is defined like this:

```
#define READREG(address)    (*(uint32_t*)(address))
```

As you can guess MISRA 2008 is not happy with the cast from unsigned long long to pointer (5-2-7/5-2-8 are reported). My question is: what is the best/appropriate way to access memory and get rid of MISRA warnings? I've tried to cast to uintptr_t before casting to pointer, but [This didn't help](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT36-C.+Converting+a+pointer+to+integer+or+integer+to+pointer).

Thank you.

Comment: A rather obvious question: since `reg_base` is actually a pointer, why not type it as `uint8_t*`?

Comment: @hidefromkgb: Or `uint32_t*`, If `reg_base` really needs to be an integer, why use `uint64_t` rather than `uintptr_t`? (MISRA probably wouldn't like that either, but `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` is the most logical type to for an integer holding a pointer value.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, wouldn\`t `uint32_t*` multiply FOO_REG_OFFSET by 4 when adding to `reg_base`?

Comment: @hidefromkgb: It depends on the exact meaning of `FOO_REG_OFFSET`. Is it an offset in bytes or in 32-bit words? I might use `unsigned char*` rather than `uint8_t*` -- though they're nearly equivalent on any system where `uint8_t` exists.

Comment: Guys, reg_base comes from a higher layer and it's an 64-bit address (e.g: 0xffffff8001218000). FOO_REG_OFFSET is offset in bytes.

Comment: the address 0x123 is not a valid address on a 64bit architecture.  and value `FOO_REG_OFFSET`, because it is a 64bit architecture would multiply the value by 8 when adding to the `reg_base` value,  Suggest passing in `reg_base` as a pointer so the addition of the offset will work as expected.

Comment: MISRA wouldn't allow this. And this code is not portable. It depends on your memory alignment. You can have predefined structures, or arrays at fixed memory location.

Comment: There is no MISRA-C from 2008. Just MISRA-C++. Are you running MISRA-C++ 2008 on your C code? Are you compiling C code as C++?

Answer (score 1):

OK a few things here - first of all, your definition for `READ_REG` is missing a `volatile` -- it should be something like

```
#define READREG(address)    (*(uint32_t volatile *)(address))
```

Secondly - and this is CPU-specific of course - generally speaking, reading a 32-bit value from an odd address (offset 0x123) won't work - at a minimum it will be slow (multiple bus cycles), and on many architectures, you'll hit a processor exception.  (BTW, please note that pointer arithmetic doesn't come into play here, since the 2 values are added before being cast to a pointer.)

To answer your original question:

> what is the best/appropriate way to access memory and get rid of MISRA
>   warnings

Well -- you ***are*** violating a MISRA rule (you have to in this case, we've all been there...) so you will get a warning.

So what you need to do is suppress the warning(s) in a disciplined, systematic and easily identifiable way.  In my opinion, there is no better example and explanation of this than in the [Quantum Platform](http://www.state-machine.com/) (QP) Event-driven framework's code, which is open source.  Specifically:

- Check out the [QP's MISRA Compliance](http://www.state-machine.com/doc/AN_QP-C_MISRA.pdf) matrix for examples of how this is handled -- for example, just search the PDF for the `Q_UINT2PTR_CAST` macro
- Check out the QP's actual source code - for example, the [macro that wraps/encapsulates such "int to ptr" casts](http://www.state-machine.com/qpc/qep_8h_source.html#l00195) (this way they are done in a manner that is easy to identify, and easy to change/suppress warnings for in a single place)
- Lastly, check out the PC-Lint config file qpc.lnt, where you can see how/where the warnings are suppressed in a single place.  THis is explained in [this app note](http://www.state-machine.com/doc/AN_QP-Cpp_MISRA.pdf), section 6.3:

> 6.3 Rule 5-2-8(req)
>
> An object with integer type or pointer to void type shall not be
>   converted to an object with pointer type.
>
> The QP/C++ applications might deviate from rule 5-2-8 when they need
>   to access specific hard-coded hardware addresses directly. The QP/C++
>   framework encapsulates this deviation in the macro `Q_UINT2PTR_CAST()`.
>   The following code snippet provides a use case of this macro:
>   `#define QK_ISR_EXIT() . . . \`
>   `*Q_UINT2PTR_CAST(uint32_t, 0xE000ED04U) = \`

I don't have time to talk about MISRA warning suppresions, compliance issues, etc. but the above gives you everything you need.

P.S.  Not sure which MISRA guidelines you are referring to -- for C, there are the 2004 & 2012 guidelines, and for C++, there are the 2008 guidelines (I know, it's almost 2017!)

Comment: #define FOO_REG_OFFSET 0x00000123 was just an example. Of course I don't have odd offsets.

Comment: @AndreiSS - of course you don't.  You also don't have an accepted answer for this question.